# How to start an application automatically after opening a lock Screen in android?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I want to build an application which will start automatically after lock screen of android mobile. Where can I get more Info about lock screen and home screen of android mobile?

Answer (score 1):

Create a broadcast receiver that detects the screen coming on.  Have it launch your activity.  Then when the lock screen is dismissed, your activity will be on top.

Answer (score 0):

See source code of mylockforandroid 
https://code.google.com/p/mylockforandroid/source/browse/

and you will need use 
DeviceAdminReceiver
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/admin/DeviceAdminReceiver.html

for disableing default android screenlock.

for starting your activity when user unlock screen register an `Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON` and `Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF` as:

add this code in manifast.xml register ScreenReceiver as:

```
<receiver android:name=".ScreenReceiver">
 <intent-filter>
 <action android:name="android.intent.action.SCREEN_OFF"/>
 <action android:name="android.intent.action.SCREEN_ON"/>
 </intent-filter>
 </receiver>
```

and add an ScreenReceiver.java as:

```
public class ScreenReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
         if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON))
         {
            Intent intent = new Intent();  
            intent.setClass(context, ScreenLockActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);          
         }
```